# How to return back from the bibliography page to the referring page after viewing the reference in Latex or Beamer?

Tags: cross-referencing, beamer, hyperref

We can go to the bibliography page by clicking on the citation inside a document or in Beamer. It will be very flexible if we can come back to the same page where we clicked before. Otherwise, we have to scroll back again to the page where we left. Is there any possible way in Latex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very good question.
To do that you just need to put the following command inside every bibtex citation, where label name is unique for each reference.

```
note={\label{1}\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{Go to Text}
```

Example:

```
@inproceedings{bibitem,
title={How to cross reference bib item},
author={x,y,z},
booktitle={Latex},
pages={1--6},
year={2021},
note={\label{1}\Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{Go to Text}}
```

This will create a hyperlink (Go to Text) beside the bibliography item.

Now if you are using \usepackage{hyperref} then the above will create a bounding box around each citation.
If you want to remove that just replace that package by

```
\usepackage[breaklinks=true, color links=true, linkcolor=black, urcolor=black, citecolor=black,bookmarks=true, bookmarkopenlevel=2]{hyperref}
```

Hurray!!! Play around with your code.

Comment: Please don't sugegst to use the `colorlinks` option which beamer documents, this will completely destroy the carefully constructed layout of footlines etc.  Also beamer loads hyperref by default, so you will be causing a server error due an option clash.

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is the `backref` option of the `biblatex` package. This will add a link in the bibliography, which will bring you back to the frame with the citation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \cite{knuth:ct}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another possibility is to let your pdf viewer do the work. For example Adobe reader has a "Previous View" option which will bring you to the frame from which you came:

[image]

(the shown keyboard shortcut is for mac, it might be different on other operating systems)